# devIL ilLoad error 1285

Tags: c++, opengl, loading, textures, devil

I'm Having an issue with loading an image with devIL for openGL

in an earlier part of my project i call

```
ilInit();
```

in a function right after i call my load just like this

```
//generate a texture
ilGenImages( 1, &uiTextureHandle );

//bind our image
ilBindImage( uiTextureHandle );

//load
//ilLoad( IL_PNG, (const ILstring)"fake.png" );
ilLoad( IL_PNG, "fake.png" );
```

for the sake of error tracking i did place "ilGetError()" after every call
which returned 0 for all of these except for ilLoad which returns 1285

after some searching i figured out that this is a lack of memory error.

so ilLoad always returns 0 and not loaded.

anyone know what im doing incorrect as for my loading or if i forgot to do something
because i feel i might have forgotten something and thats the reason why 1285 appears.

Comment: i also just tested to see if i can load another image format my test subject was a ".bmp" and that load didn't give me any errors

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for `ilLoad()` to fail with `IL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` is simply if the PNG file you're using is corrupt.

However, 1285 means `IL_INVALID_VALUE` - it means the path you're giving it is likely wrong.  Try an absolute path (remembering that back slashes aren't okay in C++ unless you use double slashes).

I personally have used DevIL for quite some time and did like it.  However, I urge you to consider FreeImage.  It has a bit more development going on and is quite stable - I used it in a commercial engine for all my image needs, and it integrates decently well with DirectX/OpenGL much like DevIL.